Toast importar libreria
tengo un problema para importar esta librería para hacer Toast con diseño.
com.github.johnpersano:supertoasts:1.3.4
Inicialmente me permite agregar la librería pero luego no me deja importarla en el MainActivity
SuperActivityToast.create(getActivity(), new Style(), Style.TYPE_BUTTON)
    .setButtonText("UNDO")
    .setButtonIconResource(R.drawable.ic_undo)
    .setOnButtonClickListener("good_tag_name", null, onButtonClickListener)
    .setProgressBarColor(Color.WHITE)
    .setText("Email deleted")
    .setDuration(Style.DURATION_LONG)
    .setFrame(Style.FRAME_LOLLIPOP)
    .setColor(PaletteUtils.getSolidColor(PaletteUtils.MATERIAL_PURPLE))
    .setAnimations(Style.ANIMATIONS_POP).show();

Gracias

Hola. Te aconsejaría que leas las advertencias en las librerías que vas a usar. En SuperToasts dice lo siguiente: This repository has been archived by the owner on Jun 30, 2024. It is now read-only. y tiene un estatus Public archive. Significa que esa librería no recibirá más actualizaciones. Si en un futuro hay bugs, problemas de compatibilidad, de seguridad u otros, no serán corregidos y tu aplicación puede fallar o peor aún, terminar siendo insegura...

... Además, hablando de la UI, creo que con Jetpack Compose podrás hacer, con unas cuantas líneas de código, lo que al parecer hace esta librería. De todos modos, si el código no funciona, muestra cómo estás incluyendo la dependencia en tu archivo app/build.gradle y además la traza del error, poniéndolo como texto en la pregunta.

En el caso de esta biblioteca la documentación es incorrecta, actualmente debes definir la dependencia en tu build.gradle usando implementation y además te sugiero usar la versión 2.0:
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.johnpersano:supertoasts:2.0'
}

Este proyecto https://github.com/jmp-12/SuperToasts  no se le da mantenimiento hace varios años, te sugiero revisar si es compatible con tu proyecto android.

Te sugiero empezar a usar Jetpack Compose, como ejemplo puedes crear un Snackbar parecido al de la biblioteca que tratas de usar.
val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()

LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
        message = "Email deleted",
        actionLabel = "UNDO"
    )
}

Scaffold(scaffoldState = scaffoldState) {
    // contenido!
}

